# Creating a Gantt chart error

Tags: errors, pgfkeys, pgfgantt

Comes up with error pgfkeys:I do not know the key /pgfgantt/group peaks. I for the life of me cant seem to find what is wrong. Can anybody help me with this please? Thanks

```
% Out line proposal

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\title{Outline Proposal}
\author{Teresa Green}

% End of preamble, beginning of proposal outline document

\begin{document}
\maketitle    begin{figure}[ftbp]
\section{Workplan}
\begin{sideways}
\begin{minipage}{20cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
y unit chart=0.5cm,
vgrid,hgrid, 
title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
title left shift=.05,
title right shift=-.05,
title height=1,
bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
incomplete/.style={fill=white},
progress label text={},
bar height=0.7,
group right shift=0,
group top shift=.6,
group height=.3,
group peaks={}{}{.2}]{34}

%labels

\gantttitle{Project}{34} \\
\gantttitle{Sep}{1} 
\gantttitle{Oct}{4} 
\gantttitle{Nov}{4} 
\gantttitle{Dec}{4} 
\gantttitle{Jan}{4} 
\gantttitle{Feb}{4} 
\gantttitle{Mar}{4} 
\gantttitle{Apr}{4} 
\gantttitle{May}{4}  
\gantttitle{Jun}{1}\
%tasks

\ganttbar{Outline Proposal}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar{Research}{3}{8} \\
\ganttbar{Literature Review}{9}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Ethics Test}{11}{15} \\
\ganttbar[progress=33]{Progress Report}{20}{22} \\
\ganttbar{Final Report}{18}{19} \\
\ganttbar{task 7}{16}{18} \\
\ganttbar[progress=0]{Demonstration}{21}{34}

%relations

\ganttlink{elem0}{elem1} 
\ganttlink{elem0}{elem3} 
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2} 
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4} 
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem5} 
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem5} 
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem6} 
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem6} 
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem7} 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{center}
\caption{Gantt Chart - Workplan}
\end{minipage}
\end{sideways}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can start by moving the \caption out of the minipage and sideways environments and \section out of the figure environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 9):

`ganttchart` takes two mandatory argumenst so I changed `{34}` to `{1}{34}` and I didn't see a `group peaks` key but there are keys starting with that string so I picked `group keys height` here, not sure what was intended. This runs without error.

I used `sidewaysfigure` since you are using that package anyway, also there is no `f` option for floats.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\title{Outline Proposal}
\author{Teresa Green}

% End of preamble, beginning of proposal outline document

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Workplan}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}

\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
y unit chart=0.5cm,
vgrid,hgrid, 
title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
title left shift=.05,
title right shift=-.05,
title height=1,
bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
incomplete/.style={fill=white},
progress label text={},
bar height=0.7,
group right shift=0,
group top shift=.6,
group height=.3,
group peaks height =.2
]
{1}{34}
%labels
\gantttitle{Project}{34} \\
\gantttitle{Sep}{1} 
\gantttitle{Oct}{4} 
\gantttitle{Nov}{4} 
\gantttitle{Dec}{4} 
\gantttitle{Jan}{4} 
\gantttitle{Feb}{4} 
\gantttitle{Mar}{4} 
\gantttitle{Apr}{4} 
\gantttitle{May}{4}  
\gantttitle{Jun}{1}\\
%tasks
\ganttbar{Outline Proposal}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar{Research}{3}{8} \\
\ganttbar{Literature Review}{9}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Ethics Test}{11}{15} \\
\ganttbar[progress=33]{Progress Report}{20}{22} \\
\ganttbar{Final Report}{18}{19} \\
\ganttbar{task 7}{16}{18} \\
\ganttbar[progress=0]{Demonstration}{21}{34}

%relations

\ganttlink{elem0}{elem1} 
\ganttlink{elem0}{elem3} 
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2} 
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4} 
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem5} 
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem5} 
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem6} 
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem6} 
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem7} 
\end{ganttchart}

\caption{Gantt Chart - Workplan}

\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the change log: “The keys `group right`/`left peak` and `group peaks` were replaced by `group right/left peak tip position`, `group peaks tip position`, `group right`/`left peak width`, `group peaks width`, `group right`/`left peak height` and `group peaks height`.”